# Django different filters based on category

Tags: html, django

I want to create a complex filtering system.
The user goes into different categories, and he will see different filters for the model based on the category he is at.

It all needs to be on one HTML page. Any ideas?
(Sorry if it's a bit hard to understand I just don't really know how to describe it.)

Comment: It has to do with database design (nothing with django). Probably you need to create a `filters` table which will save the filters of each category. Each category should have attributes e.g. (RAM,CPU,GRAPHICS CARD) that can be used and reused when you create a product. (e.g. laptop). Now you know that the `laptop` category has attributes like (Ram.CPU,etc). You can select a category which will bring the attributes and select which one you want to include in the filters.

Comment: I suggest using dba stackexchange to ask this question. Start from the database design and clear it in your mind in high level (See how Woocommerce dashboard works) then come to django. https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How many different categories and different filters per category? If they are small numbers, you may not have to do this in the database.